# How to declare a variable with razor syntax within javascript block for a razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have created a razor view (Demo.cshtml) and I tried to declare razor variable within javascript block as shown below:

Code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Demo";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>
    Demo</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        @{
            bool test = true;
         }

    });
</script>
```

I am getting few warnings as mentioned below:

Warning 1   Invalid character   Demo.cshtml 10  10
Warning 2   Expected ';'    Demo.cshtml 11  18

Can anyone guide me in resolving the above warning?

Comment: why you want to use a razor view inside javascript, when you can already declare variables in javascript?

Comment: I am trying to use the razor variable within the javascript function.

Answer (score 1):

Well its not so easy to explain. For different needs you can use different solutions.

The easiest way is to use 'text' tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @{
        <text>

        alert(@myVar);

        </text>
    }

</script>
```

And for example for String values you can do like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("admin", new { controller = "users"})';
</script>
```

For boolean types you can do like in this example, but it looks like a stupid hack :)

```
var bool = '@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid' == "True";
```

And for collections you need to implement some helper method to be able to call

```
var myArray = @Html.ToJson(MyCSharpCollectionObject)
```